# ASP.NET MBCompression for Chinese language with jQuery UI and jQGrid

Tags: asp.net, encoding, compression

We developing our multilanguage site using the following components:

**MBCompresion** - we used source files of that library to integrate JS / CSS minify and compression. In addition we wrote HttpFilter that combines all JS / CSS on page to a single request (one for JS one for CSS). We are using FileSystemStorage from MBCompression as a caching strategy.

**jQueryUI Datepicker** - We use it as is, include localization files.

**jQGrid** - Same, we use it as is, include localization files.

All of that works fine..."script" tags on ASPX page are combined to single "script" tag. It make request to jslib.axd HttpHandler, handler combines all JS files to a single file, compress it with GZip, saves the compressed file on FileSystem and then send that file to client.

**Problem**: The only problem is when site switched to Chinese language. When site is on Chinese, with GZip compression and FileSystem cache, the javascript that arrives to client is invalid - it contains strange characters and errors like "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL ".  After some investigations, i found the problem only with Chinese localized files of jqGrid and jQuery Datepicker.
Here is example (just some rows) of javascript that arrives to client:

```
jQuery(function($){$.datepicker.regional['zh']={closeText:'s�',prevText:'&#x3c;
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
',nextText:'&#x3e;',currentText:'�)',monthNames:['','�','   ','�','�','m','','k',']','A','A','A�'],monthNamesShort:['','�','    ','�','�','m','','k',']','A','A','A�'],dayNames:['�','','�','   ','�','�','m'],dayNamesShort:['h�','h','h�','h  ','h�','h�','hm'],dayNamesMin:['�','','�',' ','�','�','m'],weekHeader:'h',dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',firstDay:1,isRTL:false,showMonthAfterYear:true,yearSuffix:'t'};$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['zh']);});
```

When I disable GZip compression, everithing workd fine. When I change cache to OutputCache, everithing works to...the only problem, when I use GZip with FileSystemCache on Chinese. All other languages (even Japanies) works perfect.

I even don't know what can be a problem. I thought that it can be related to Encoding or something, but I don't see such parameters or properties on FileStream that write compressed JS to file.

Please help me to solve that problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Strange. What encoding are the Chinese files stored in?

Comment: @AlexDn: You included many tags in your question. The JavaScript files with Chinese localisation of jqGrid and jQuery Datepicker are just common JavaScript files saved as UTF-8. So I suppose that your existing problem is **pure `MBCompresion`** only. I recommend you remove unneeded tags and try to address the problem only to [MBCompresion](http://mbcompression.codeplex.com/) specialists. You can consider to replace `[.net]` tag to `[asp.net]` and remove both `[jqgrid]` and `[jquery-ui]`.

Comment: @Oleg changed some tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!!! The problem was in MBCompression StringToBytes method in Utils class:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Convert string to byte[]
        /// <para>Faster than the built-in method, and prevent encoding problems</para>
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="stringValue"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static byte[] StringToBytes(string value)
        {
            int length = value.Length;
            byte[] resultBytes = new byte[length];
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                resultBytes[i] = (byte)value[i];
            }
            return resultBytes;
        }
```

I changed this method to:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Convert string to byte[]
        /// <para>Faster than the built-in method, and prevent encoding problems</para>
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="stringValue"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static byte[] StringToBytes(string value)
        {
            Encoding Utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
            return Utf8.GetBytes(value);
        }
```

Now it looks like everything is working, include Chinese.

Comment: Like I supposed the solution was really pure `MBCompresion` problem.